# Do Not purge image when updating record in Rails 6 Active Storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-activestorage

I've been researching this issue for a couple days and can't seem to find a solution.

I have a model in Rails 6 for bars that `has_one_attached :image`

A user can create a new bar and attach an image. This works fine.

When a user edits bar information like a bar's name and submits that information Active Storage purges the originally uploaded image by default, even if no new image was submitted.

During an edit, if a user does not submit a new image, and ONLY changes the record, e.g., Bar Name, how do I keep Active Storage from automatically purging the image? I would like to keep the image associated with the Bar record.

I have tried `dependent: :purge_later` in my model to no success. I have also tried submitting params without the image param `if bar_info.image.attached?`

My Model bar_info.rb

```
class BarInfo < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :bar_specials, dependent: :destroy
    has_one_attached :image
    validates :user_id, presence: true
    validates :barname, presence: true, length: { maximum: 100 }
    validates :city, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
    validates :state, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
    validates :image, content_type: { in: %w[image/jpeg image/gif image/png],
                                            message: "must be a valid image format" },
                          size:         { less_than: 5.megabytes,
                                          message: "should be less than 5MB" }
end
```

My Controller bar_infos_controller.rb

```
class BarInfosController < ApplicationController
def update
        @bar_info = BarInfo.find(params[:id])
        @bar_info.user_id = current_user.id
        @bar_info.image.attach(params[:bar_info][:image])
        if @bar_info.update(bar_info_params)
            flash[:notice] = "Bar Info Updated!"
            redirect_to bar_info_path(@bar_info)
        else
            render "edit"
        end
end

private

        def bar_info_params
            attributes = [ :barname, :city, :state, :image ]
            params.require(:bar_info).permit(attributes)
        end
end
```

My Edit View _form.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md 6">
        <%= form_with(model: @bar_info, local: true) do |f| %>
        <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

        <%= f.label "Bar Name (required)" %>
        <%= f.text_area :barname, placeholder: "Bar name here", class: "form-control", size: "70x1" %>

        <%= f.label "City (required)" %>
        <%= f.text_area :city, placeholder: "San Diego", class: "form-control", size: "70x1" %>

        <%= f.label "State (required)" %>
        <%= f.select :state, CS.states(:us), class: "form-control" %>

        <span class="image">
            <p>Upload an image of Bar here!</p>
            <%= f.file_field :image, accept: "image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png" %>
        </span>

        <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        <% end %>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#bar_info_image").bind("change", function() {
                const size_in_megabytes = this.files[0].size/1024/1024;
                if (size_in_megabytes > 5) {
                    alert("Maximum file size is 5MB. Please choose a smaller file.");
                    $("$bar_info_image").val("");
                }
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

bar_infos routes:

```
bar_infos     GET    /bar_infos(.:format)          bar_infos#index
              POST   /bar_infos(.:format)          bar_infos#create
new_bar_info  GET    /bar_infos/new(.:format)      bar_infos#new
edit_bar_info GET    /bar_infos/:id/edit(.:format) bar_infos#edit
bar_info      GET    /bar_infos/:id(.:format)      bar_infos#show
              PATCH  /bar_infos/:id(.:format)      bar_infos#update
              PUT    /bar_infos/:id(.:format)      bar_infos#update
              DELETE /bar_infos/:id(.:format)      bar_infos#destroy
```

TL;DR I'd like to edit a bar's name and still keep the original image that was uploaded with it. Active Storage currently purges that image on update.

Thank you.

Comment: What happens in the console if you try to update there `Bar.find(1).update(name: 'something')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of this line in your `update` controller action:

```rb
      def update 
        ...
        @bar_info.image.attach(params[:bar_info][:image])
        ...
      end
```

if user doesn't fill in the image in edit action you will set image to `nil` which deletes the file from activestorage. You should leave this update completely on ActiveRecords `update` action. You have image in your permitted params so it should work without any problems:

```rb
      def update
        @bar_info = BarInfo.find(params[:id])
        @bar_info.user_id = current_user.id

        if @bar_info.update(bar_info_params)
          flash[:notice] = "Bar Info Updated!"
          redirect_to bar_info_path(@bar_info)
        else
          render "edit"
        end
      end

private

      def bar_info_params
        attributes = [ :barname, :city, :state, :image ]
        params.require(:bar_info).permit(*attributes)
      end
```

(also I think there should be `*` in [permit](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit) call `params.require(:bar_info).permit(*attributes)`)

Comment: Thank you, I updated it with your solution and it works fine. Original code was from the Michael Hartl Ruby on Rails 6th ed., for anyone else who may come from that background.